# Port forwarding on a slave router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, switch

I'm having a little struggle with the situation below. First I'll explain the basic setup which used to work:

1. Wireless 4-port LAN router from the internet company
2. Static IP for an IP Camera
3. NAT port 80 forwarding to the static IP address

Then there was need for another camera, but since 3 ports (printer, creditcard/pin, alarm system) where taken, there was only 1 LAN port available. I took an old Wireless router and connected it as follows:

1. Router #1 uses IP address 192.168.1.1 with DHCP on. IP pool .3 - .253
2. Router #2 uses IP address 192.168.1.2 with DHCP off and DNS (prim/sec) to .1
3. Port #4 on router #1 goes to Port #1 on router #2
4. Both cameras are connected to ports #2 and #3 on the slave router

The full network is functional, it works as expected. But here comes the strange thing: router #1 doesn't see any hardware connected to `.132` (Camera #1 static IP) and `.133` (Camera #2 static IP). While both can be managed via the internal IP address in the browser.

I tried 2 situations so far:

- In router #1 I specified port 80 to forward to .132
- In router #1 I specified port 80 to forward to .2 (Slave router) and in router #2 I specified port 80 to forward to .132 (camera)

Both did not deliver the expected results, while the internal IP addresses work to manage the camera. Connecting from a different computer using the outgoing IP address results in a 404 page.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Port 80 seems to be working now! I just can't get any page on the 8080 port!

Comment: Did you port forward port 8080?

Comment: yes, I've opened port 8080 and then forwarded port 8080 to the IP address (.133) with port 80